# how to set GitHub action to comment on new PR?

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to integrate `github-action-comment-pull-request` from the official GitHub [marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-action-comment-pull-request).

This will be my yaml:

```
on: [pull_request]

jobs:
    build:
        name: Comment a pull_request
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: Checkout
              uses: actions/checkout@v2

            - name: Comment a pull_request
              uses: mb2dev/github-action-comment-pull-request@1.0.0
              with:
                message: "Hello, Thank you for this PR!"
                GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

My problem is that I want the message to be shown for all new PRs except PRs raised by specific users: userA, userB.
Preferably also to exclude users for a specific GitHub team.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this workflow to run the job for everyone except for specific users, an option could be to add an `if` condition to your job to run only if the `github.actor` from the [Github context](https://docs.github.com/pt/github-ae@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts) isn't among a list of users you set.

**Example with your workflow:**

```yaml
on: [pull_request]

jobs:
    build:
        name: Comment a pull_request
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        if: ${{ github.actor != 'Slava' }}
        steps:
            - name: Checkout
              uses: actions/checkout@v2

            - name: Comment a pull_request
              uses: mb2dev/github-action-comment-pull-request@1.0.0
              with:
                message: "Hello, Thank you for this PR!"
                GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

This also work for many users if you add `&&` or `||` inside the condition.

**For example, I use this workflow with some of my repositories to add PR comments:**

```yaml
name: PR Comment

on:
  pull_request_target:
    types: 
      - opened

jobs:
  PR-Comment:
    if: github.actor != 'user1' && github.actor != 'user2' && github.actor != 'user3' && github.actor != 'user4' && github.actor != 'user5'  
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: PR Comment
      uses: actions/github-script@v2
      with:
        github-token: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
        script: |
          github.issues.createComment({
            issue_number: ${{ github.event.number }},
            owner: context.repo.owner,
            repo: context.repo.repo,
            body: ':warning: Have you followed the [contributions guidance](<contribution_guidance_url>)? Content PRs should generally be made against the the [source repo](https://github.com/<owner>/<repo>).'
          })
```

[A full workflow example can be found in this repo](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/29-check-actor-pr-or-push.yml)

I don't think it's possible to use or inform the Github Team directly with a condition yet.

Comment: Do you know if the condition can work with teams? I was also wondering about allow list parameter for example as shown on https://github.com/cla-assistant/github-action

Comment: I believe it's possible to create a list and check in the condition if the `github.actor` is inside it, with the `contains()` method. I've never done it though.